# Parallax effect refresh rate in IE is horrible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I made a new website and got a little parallax effect on it. In Chrome, Firefox, Safari, even on mobile devices it works perfectly, but not in Internet Explorer. You can check it out here:
 [My Website](http://tundt.tk) 
In Internet Explorer it refreshes like after 3 seconds. Is this possible to fix somehow? 
I added 
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` 
to my page. That fixed some text-shadows etc.
If it isn't possible to fix, it's not that bad, because i guess nobody uses Internet Explorer nowadays or *shouldn't* use Internet Explorer at least.

Comment: Did you ever get materializecss parallax working on Internet Explorer? I see you've switched your website to bootstrap.

Comment: If I'm not compeletely wrong, it's working atm on IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 5 of your style.css you have `transition: all .2s ease-in-out;`

Remove it and it will work in explorer. You don't need CSS transition when you're using jquery animation.

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out; /* <-- Remove this line */
}
```